# Js function not working properly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I have a login page in html and i have used a Js function to call the api. The code is

```
function submitdetails() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var params = JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password });
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200){ 
                if(xmlhttp.responseText == "AdminLogin"){
                            // Redirect Url to Ldap Configuration settings page
                            window.location.href = "Configure.html";
                }else{
                     var cook = document.cookie;
                    document.getElementById("login_form").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    //document.getElementById("login_form").innerHTML = cook

                }
            }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("login_form").innerHTML = "Error"; 
                }
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST","http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/",true);     
        xmlhttp.send(params);
    }
```

The above code works perfectly fine in IE . But when i try it in Chrome , the fucntion return's to "else statement" which returns error in it.

Comment: What error? That's kind of important.

Comment: Chrome has a very nice Javascript debugger, you should try using it. [Here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/) a tutorial.

Comment: you're getting the error because xmlhttp.status does not equal 200. before solving the issue we should know what's happening. add console.log(xmlhttp.status) in the else that contains the error. and toggle console and see what the status is

Comment: I think it's working on IE and not chrome because of some security whole that chrome fixed years ago and IE did not. Check the console it's probably saying exactly that.

Comment: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." This is what i am getting in the console

Comment: This code is it runnig from `http://localhost/..` or from `file://...`?

Comment: looks like a security issue. see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Answer (score 0):

Seem this is a CORS problem. Your backend have may an entry like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This work well on IE but not on Firefox and Chrome.

> Firefox and Chrome require exact domain specification in
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. For servers with authentication,
>   these browsers do not allow "*" in this header. The
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header must contain the value of the
>   Origin header passed by the client.

So you have to adjust your backend CORS settings.
Here the header definitions for CORS from [MDM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin)